# PHP and Apache "php5_module' in file /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so is garbled"

Tags: php, compilation

Lately, I have been trying to compile php on my old PPC mac running OS X 10.4. As can be seen by looking at my past questions, I have been having problems. It is finally compiled and installed, and I was about ready to start apache, begin programming, and breathe a sigh of relief to discover that on running "/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start," it returned yet another error:

> $ ./apachectl start
>   Syntax error on line 232 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
>   API module structure 'php5_module' in file /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so is garbled - expected signature 41503230 but saw 41503232 - perhaps this is not an Apache module DSO, or was compiled for a different Apache version?

I assume that the apache version, 2.0.64 is incompatible with the php version, 5.3.12, but I cannot find an older version of php, or a newer one that seems to work with my system.

Comment: It seems you need to compile libphp5.so for that apache version specifically.

Comment: @AlexLunix I checked around, but couldn't find any information on how to do that. I am kind of new to compiling php, so I would appreciate it if you could point me in the direction of some reference to do with compiling libphp5.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer to my problem and finally got php and apache working both, together. After a little more in depth research, I found out that some people encountering the same issue had fixed it by messing with libpng ([Here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/solaris-opensolaris-20/error-while-starting-apache-with-php-711260/page2.html)). I assumed that there was some unknown issue with libpng, and because I don't need it, I just recompiled "--without-png-dir."

Glad that it works and now I can begin programming!